# How to generate 32 bit UUID in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uuid

I know that can generate a UUID with [NSUUID](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/index.html):

```
NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

But this is 128-bit values.

I want to get a 32-bit UUID how to do that?

Comment: [What's "32-bit UUID"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4267475/335858)

Comment: I think the docs might mean "UUID with RFC 4122 version 4" whose bytes are random, not that it's 4 bytes long. @isaced: could you take the generated UUID, convert it to a number, & 0xffffffff, then convert the result back to NSString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A UUID by definition  is 128-bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

`A UUID is a 16-octet (128-bit) number.`

I believe you can make a 32-bit Unique identifier [but it is advised against](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649889/how-get-unique-integer-value-in-iphone). 
If you really need to make a 32 bit Unique identifier [here](http://preshing.com/20121224/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-unique-random-integers) is a pseudo code tutorial that might help.